# Page slide in/out transition for android/iOS apps

Tags: mobile, android, transitions

**Is there a generally accepted duration for sliding transitions in android/iOS that feels "natural"**? In a similar vein, do these transitions accelerate, or do they move at a constant speed?

I'm working with an app that uses slide gestures, but the transitions associated with them are slow, creating a feeling of input lag. Our developer is overseas, so I need to figure out what feels natural without testing it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a bit on this in [Google's Material Design Guide](http://www.google.co.uk/design/spec/animation/authentic-motion.html#authentic-motion-mass-weight). Amongst the guidelines:

- Don't: Linear motion feels mechanical.
- Accelerate objects swiftly and decelerate them slowly to avoid abrupt changes in velocity.
- When an object enters the frame, ensure that it's moving at its peak velocity.

The android also has [animation duration constants](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.integer.html) - short(200ms), medium(400ms) and long(500ms).

As [this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/crossfade.html#setup) suggests, a view crossfading should be done using the short duration.